# The life of Jesus in the Quran

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, prophet-isa

Jesus in the Quran was not crucified and lived to be a very old man before he died.  Does The Holy Quran or the hadiths reveal that the Muslim Jesus took a wife or had children?

Comment: No, Jesus was lifted up to the heavens and will return in the end of times, he did not grow old and die.

Comment: There is no indication in the Quran or Hadith about whether he had a wife or children, it is claimed by some that he did not but there is no solid evidence for either position. Jesus عليهم السلام  did not live to be a very old man before he died, rather he was raised up alive ([3:55](https://quran.com/3/55), [4:157-159](https://legacy.quran.com/4/157-159)), and he will return in the future to complete his ministry ([hadith](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/34)).